# trying to solve 8th project euler number 8

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is the link of the problem.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=8

below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long i,sum;
    long temp = 0;
    long arr[1000] = {
    // Increasingly large number is ommitted//
    // I just add ',' between each numbers//};

    for(i=0; i<988; i++){
        sum = arr[i]*arr[i+1]*arr[i+2]*arr[i+3]*arr[i+4]*arr[i+5]*arr[i+6]
             *arr[i+7]*arr[i+8]*arr[i+9]*arr[i+10]*arr[i+11]*arr[i+12];
        if(temp<sum){
            temp = sum;
        }
    }

    printf("%ld",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

so I got 2091059712 which seems kind of reasonable answer.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Please specify your actual question

Comment: FYI: What you got is not the right answer.  Its around 23,xxx,xxx,xxx so as Floris says, you need to be using a larger-capacity variable (e.g. `long long`)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is, that you did not account for the size of the product. An integer is 10 digits max (2,147,483,647). So this or something alike might happen:

```
sum = 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9;
```

This gives: 2,541,865,828,329 which overflows your integer leading to undefined behaviour.

Use a larger integer type or take a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

That's a brute force solution that will work fine for this size of problem.

Potential improvements:

- Split the array on "0", and only test the substrings that are longer than the desired length.
- Print out the numbers that ended up being the best substring. That way you can test that it actually is present in the original and the multiplication is done correctly.